# How can I get text inside of <span> using puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, puppeteer

Having the following html:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 nopaddingright">
    <ul class="account-statics clearright">
        <li>
          <span class="title">Title1</span>
          <span class="value fs13 ">value1</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class="title">Title2</span>
          <span class="value fs13 ">value2</span>
          <ul class="account-sub">
            <li>
              <span class="title">Title3</span>
              <span class="value fs13 ">value3</span>
            </li>
            <li>
              <span class="title">Title4</span>
              <span class="value fs13 ">value4</span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class="title">Title5</span>
          <span class="value fs13 ">value5</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I wanna get the text inside of all second  elements.

I tried this way:

```
const element = await page.$('div > ul[class="account-statics clearright"] > ul > li:nth-child(2) > span:nth-child(2)');
```

And another way:

```
const elements= await page.$$('span[class="value fs13 "]');
```

But both attempts didn't work. How can I solve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"?

Answer (score 0):

```
const sp = await page.$x('//*[contains(@class, "fs13")]');    
const spanName = await (await sp.getProperty('textContent')).jsonValue();
```

The following code will get you the span text assuming the class name in span is fs13.

There shouldnot be '.' infront of fs13 in $x function. It should be only fs13 as we have already mentioned it is class